# Is it possible to only change the alpha-transparency part of a color?

Tags: css

I have some css like this:

```
   a
      transition: all 0.4s ease-out
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, 0)
   a:hover
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, 1)
```

This gives me an underline on my buttons that fades in. I would like the underline to always use the same color as the rest of the element, specified using for example

```
color: rgb(256, 256, 256)
```

I want this setup so that I don't have to respecify my colors every time I add a border. I can't use `opacity`, because the element has stuff in it.

Comment: Not sure if im understanding this correctly, but isnt this where a SASS variable would come into play? ie something along the lines of:

$maincolor: rgba(255,255,255, 1)

color: $maincolor;
border: ($maincolor .5);

[This article covers it in scss](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/mixins-for-semi-transparent-colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `opacity`, if you apply it to an `::after` pseudo-element:

```css
body {
background-color: #000;
}

a {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

a:nth-of-type(1) {
color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

a:nth-of-type(3) {
color: rgba(127,191,255,1);
}

a::after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 1px;
background-color: currentColor;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

a:hover::after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a>The quick brown</a>
<a>fox jumps over</a>
<a>the lazy dog.</a>
```

Comment: this is great, however, in my solution, the a-tag spans multiple lines, can you get this solution to work with that somehow?

Comment: I have tweaked my original answer (above) and posted the new answer - for **multi-line links** - below. (It needs to be a different answer, I think, because it's handling a different situation in a different way).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try adding the border by using a pseudo element, then you can separate color and transparency by using opacity, `currentColor` matches automatically with your link color:

```
a{
display:inline-block;
}

a::after{
border-bottom:1px solid currentColor;
opacity:0;
content:"";
display:inline-block;
width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Color `rgb(256,256,256)` is undefined.

RGB color space is from 0 to 255 
So use `rgba(255,255,255,0)` and `rgba(255,255,255,1)` and it should work.

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}
a{
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
a:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
           
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer I gave employs the `::after` *pseudo-element* and works for inline links on a single line.

This answer, for **multi-line links**, uses a similar method, but this time, the `::after` *pseudo-element* covers the entire `a` element (rather than simply being positioned at the bottom of it) and has an alternating repeating background of lines - which ends up looking like one underline for every line in the `a` element:

```css
body {
width: 400px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
}

a:nth-of-type(1) {
color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

a:nth-of-type(3) {
color: rgba(127,191,255,1);
}

a::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 12;
display: block;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 19px, currentColor 19px, currentColor 20px);
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

a:hover::after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a>The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown The quick brown</a>
<a>fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over fox jumps over </a>
<a>the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. the lazy dog. </a>
```